# Cassandra spark connector data loss

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark, datastax

Recetly we were calculating some statistics using [datastax spark connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector).
Repeated queries were returrning different results on each execution.

Background: we have approx. 112K records in 3-node cassandra cluster. The table have single partition key `UUID` column named `guid` and no clustering key columns.

This is simple `guid` extractor i defined to examine losses:

```
val guids = sc.cassandraTable[UUID]("keyspace","contracts").select("guid")
```

Next i've repeatedly extracted data to local collections several times

```
val gss = List.fill(20)(Set(guids.collect():_*))
val gsall = gss reduce (_ | _)
val lost = gss map (gsall &~ _ size)
```

Resulted `lost` is `List(5970, 7067, 6926, 6683, 5807, 7901, 7005, 6420, 6911, 6876, 7038, 7914, 6562, 6576, 6937, 7116, 7374, 6836, 7272, 7312)`

so we have `6,17±0,47%` data loss each query

Could this be the problem of cassandra, spark or connector? And in each case - are there exist some configuration way to prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've read [some docs](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#configuration-options-for-adjusting-reads) and learned that reading consistensy level could and should be set for such situations.
After declaring

```
implicit val readConf = ReadConf.fromSparkConf(sc.getConf).copy(
    consistencyLevel = ConsistencyLevel.ALL)
```

I've got my stable result.